# How can I use workspaces and have xbmc in only one of them?

Tags: unity, workspaces, xbmc

I have Workspaces enabled in Unity.

They work with fullscreen video reproduction in VLC and the default video player.

I can have a video in one workspace, a browser in another, and switch flawlessly between them.

I can do the same with the Steam video games I have tested, I can have Portal running in a workspace and Chrome in another, and switch between them.

But XBMC is something else. It somehow disables workspaces, and in order to switch, I have to close the program. XBMC responds to Alt-Tab in Windows but not in Unity.

How can I change workspaces if XBMC is running?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running XBMC in fullscreen mode, it is rather possessive. It takes control over the screen, the pointer and some other resources. This is rather useful when it is running stand-alone as a media center but annoying then ran as an desktop app.

But there is the option to put it into windowed mode. You can change the modes by pressing `\` (Backspace) or, if you have an other keyboard layout, the key combination that produceds a `\`. There are also option to set that in the Settings Menu (Video Output) and the settings files.

In windowed mode it might not use the full screen but also it should not interfere with the desktop.